# loading QA data to python chatbot tool

Tags: python, flask, chatbot, chatterbot

I have created Flask chatbot application with Python chatterbot example, but i wanted to load a specific questions and answer to the bot to display in the application. I am new to this kindly help. Thank you

Comment: You just forgot to ask the question... or at least describe what exactly is the problem you have.

Comment: ok. sorry for the confusion, let me try to explain -   I have the question and answers. is there a way I can do a bulk load these as training data. Currently I am opening a existing .YML file and entering this question and answer one by one.